# Change a value in XML file Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLConverter> 
<Positions> 
   <Side0 Chemin="face.jpg"/>
   <Side1 Chemin="droite1.jpg"/>
   <Side2 Chemin=""/> 
   <Side3 Chemin=""/> 
   <Side4 Chemin="dos.jpg"> 
       <Dos28 PositionY="0.906845" PositionX="0.602489" Nom="Dos28" NoSelect="0"/>
       <Dos29 PositionY="0.910139" PositionX="0.570278" Nom="Dos29" NoSelect="0"/> 
       <Dos26 PositionY="0.93869" PositionX="0.601025" Nom="Dos26" NoSelect="0"/> 
   </Side4> 
   <Side5 Chemin="gauche1.jpg"/> 
   <Side6 Chemin="gauche2.jpg"/> 
   <Side7 Chemin=""/> 
</Positions> 
<Marqueurs>
<Angles>
<Distances>
</XMLConverter>
```

I want to change the value of PositionY in Dos28.

I have tried this:

```
r=num2str(25);
xDoc=xmlread(fullfile(('test pour zones.xml')));
allListItems=xDoc.getElementsByTagName('Side4');
allListItems=allListItems.item(0);
thisListItem=allListItems.getElementsByTagName('Dos28');
thisListItem.setAttribute('PositionY','25');
xmlwrite('test pour zones2.xml',xDoc);
```

I have a error in Matlab: ??? No appropriate method, property, or field setAttribute for class
org.apache.xerces.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Even though matlab only finds a single element with element name 'Dos28' it still returns a list. You still need to get the first item from the list.

```
thisListItem=allListItems.getElementsByTagName('Dos28');
thisListItem=thisListItem.item(0);
thisListItem.setAttribute('PositionY','25');
```